GitHub Actions createWorkflowDispatch
I'm using a job with actions/github-script@v6 to make a call to a workflow. Is there s a way to link this call to a PR?
  call_deploy_stage_muca:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Trigger Workflow
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            const payload = context['payload'];
            console.log(payload.pull_request)
            const ref = payload.pull_request?.head?.ref;
            github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch({
              ...context.repo,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              workflow_id: 'deploy-stage.yaml',
              ref: "develop",
              inputs: { 'chosen': 'muca' }
            })

Would there be a way to link this call github.rest.actions.createWorkflowDispatch to an existing PR, so that the deploy process in the PR continues as the checks show in the image?
With the function I can execute the workflow, but it is not associated with the open PR, meaning it cannot work together.
